# Diskpart UniqueID - C# how to get that id

Tags: c#, wmi, disk, unique-id

I'm familiar with VolumeSerialNumber, i need the Disk ID same as shown in diskpart:

WD My Passport 0740 USB Device
**Disk ID: 08B29B51**
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

I can't find anything on the web (WMI) or forums that supports this request.
Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the Method i created for getting DiskID from Driveletter.**
Probably are better ways to do this, but this worked for me for now.
Thanks for all your help.

> ```
>     public static string GetDiskID(char Drive)
>     {
>         uint volumeSerialNumber = 0;
>         bool DriveFound = false;
>         foreach (ManagementObject drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select DeviceID, Signature from Win32_DiskDrive").Get())
>         {
>             foreach (ManagementObject partition in new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format("associators of {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='{0}'}} where AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition", drive["DeviceID"])).Get())
>             {
>                 if (partition != null)
>                 {
>                     ManagementObject logical = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format("associators of {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='{0}'}} where AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition", partition["DeviceID"])).First();
>                     if (logical != null)
>                     {
>                         if (logical["Name"] != null)
>                         {
>                             string logicalName = logical["Name"].ToString();
>                             if (logicalName[0] == Drive)
>                             {
>                                 volumeSerialNumber = (uint)drive["Signature"];
>                                 DriveFound = true;
>                                 break;
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             if (DriveFound)
>                 break;
>         }
>          var serial = volumeSerialNumber.ToString("x");
>             while (serial.Length < 8)
>             {
>                 serial = serial.Insert(0, "0");
>             }
>             return serial.ToUpper();
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI Class. It has a field called `Signature` which contains this ID. Note, though, that this is *not a string*, but a number. If you want to match what you see in DiskPart, you'll have to display that number as a hexadecimal string (`signature.ToString("X")`)

Here's code to print out drive signatures:

```
public void PrintDiskDriveSignature()
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
              (@"\\localhost\ROOT\CIMv2", "select * from Win32_DiskDrive");
    var drives = searcher.Get();
    foreach (var drive in drives)
    {
        string name = drive["Name"].ToString();
        uint signature = (uint) drive["Signature"];
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, signature.ToString("X"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because D: isn't a disk drive, it's a logical volume on a disk drive.